# In multiobjective optimization, how to calculate the distance to reference point?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, euclidean-distance

In multiobjective optimization, what does the distance exactly means, is it:

1) The distance from reference point (V) to an individual (Xi) (candidate solution) in the population (decision space).

```
 Euclidean Distance = d(Xi,V)
```

OR

2) The distance from reference point (V) to the objective vector f(X) in the objective space, where f(Xi) = f(f1(Xi),...fm(Xi)). m is the number of objectives.

```
Euclidean Distance = d(f(Xi),V)
```

In this paper "[Harris’s Hawk Multi-Objective Optimizer for Reference
Point Problems](http://worldcomp-proceedings.com/proc/p2016/ICA3293.pdf)", in the pseudo code, Section 4.2:

a-

> Calculate distances to reference point v for each search agent(hawk)
>   Xi on all objectives ݂fm(Xi).

and

b-

> Calculate distances to reference point vi for all ݂fm(Xi) on each
>   search agent in group

**What is the difference between a and b?**